# Drupal: Display Recent Search Results

Tags: drupal-7

I want to know if there is any functionality or module in Drupal 7 that would fetch last search results of other users.

E.g.,
  If I go to the search page then in the left column I would find the results which other users got in the previous searches.

TIA

Dushyant Joshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zeitgeist module should do that for you.

http://drupal.org/project/zeitgeist

There is pretty much a module for everything.

Comment: Thanks SpaceBeers, I installed and enabled the module but I always find the results as empty. Means I cant find any entries in "zeitgeist" table. Am I missing any settings other than default "zeitgeist"  settings?

Comment: Thanks, its working for in built search.But I have created a view for search and advanced search. So Will it work for views. I am new to Drupal.

Comment: Should do. Have a go and if it doesn't then raise it as an issue or add a new question to SO. If this answer has helped please accept it as the correct answer.